# Polite noun to refer to a colleague who is departing a company?

Tags: translation, word-requests, simplified-characters

What is a polite noun to refer to a colleague who is departing a company? 
For example, in English I might simply refer to them as a "leaver". (So someone who is leaving.) This is simple and non-offensive.  Is there a Chinese equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

离职员工 or 离职同事 is what we will use when referring to a leaving colleague, but this is very official and so only used when the audience is the general public.

Usually we only call their names and say they are leaving.

Ex: 志明不在这里工作了。